# Is it possible to have deterministic ClassCleanup in MSTest / VS Unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, mstest

i.e. to have the method decorated with ClassCleanup attribute executed once **immediately** after all tests in a test class ? (like TestFixtureTearDown in NUnit). Any workarounds ?

The alternative of embedding this heavy setup/teardown in TestInitialize and TestCleanup would just drive up the test execution times.

I was comparing the two over the past week. 
(Here's what I found [NUnit vs MSTest](http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2011/11/nunit-vs-mstest-2011-edition.html) . Don't have a lot of flying time in MSTest, so if I've made a mistake, please feel free to post corrections as comments..)

This particular item is a showstopper as far as I am concerned. Read the first section of the blog post in case you'd like more details.

Comment: Do you mean NUnit in the paranthesis in the second line? -xUnit works by using Dispose

Comment: I meant the xUnit family ; but fixed anyways to avoid confusion with xUnit.net

Answer (score 1):

> ClassInitialize and ClassCleanup are called right after your class is loaded and right before your class is unloaded.

It's true, but classes are bulk-unloaded after all tests finished running.

E.g.

ClassInitialize1
TestInitialize1
TestMethod11
TestCleanup1
TestInitialize1
TestMethod12
TestCleanup1
ClassInitialize2
TestInitialize2
TestMethod21
TestCleanup2
TestInitialize2
TestMethod22
TestCleanup2
TestInitialize2
TestMethod23
TestCleanup2
**ClassCleanup1

ClassCleanup2**

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) ClassCleanup is run as follows:

> For classes
>
> ClassInitialize and ClassCleanup are called right after your class is
>   loaded and right before your class is unloaded.

As I read it, that means when the tests in the class hae been run.

Comment: Added a community note to the vs2010 page. Take a look at the first section of the post linked in the question. What the MSDN page does not say is that "Class Cleanups are run at some point in the future as a batch. Other test classes may be executed between the last test and ClassCleanup of Class#1."